# switching activities using spinner

Tags: java, android, spinner

i have the below code and i need to fill in the `if(pos == 1){??????????}` so that i can switch activities when the first position in my spinner is selected. The name of my new acitivity is Route1.java. 
How would i write the code to switch to Route1.java when position 1 is selected in my spinner.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.Manifest.permission;

public class MyOnItemSelectedListener extends Activity 
        implements OnItemSelectedListener {

    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, 
            View view, int pos, long id) {
        if (pos == 1) {
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), 
                    "Your route is "
                    + parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString(), 
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView parent) {
        // Do nothing.
    }
}
```

the above class is used in this class

```
import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import android.R.array;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebView;

import android.widget.AbsSpinner;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class cnycentro extends Activity {        

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.cnycentro);

        Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
                this, R.array.routes, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new MyOnItemSelectedListener());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should read up on intents and more specifically explicit intents.

In order to launch explicitly a new activity (like one you created) the syntax is:

```
Intent newActivity = new Intent(this, Route1.class);
startActivity(newActivity);
```

Also be sure to add the new activity to the android manifest:

```
<activity android:name=".Route1"></activity>
```

Edit:

+1 for not extending Activity in your listener, instead simply write

```
public class MyOnItemSelectedListener implements OnItemSelectedListener {
    ....
}
```

You can write it this way if your Activity or Listener is too large and it would reduce readability to write it inline.

Answer (score 0):

1. MyOnItemSelectedListener() doesn't need to be a separate class, and it definitely shouldn't inherit from Activity.
2. Change your code to something like this:

   ```
   OnItemSelectedListener listener = new OnItemSelectedListener(){
   @Override
   public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
           int position, long id) {
       //do you really want 1 here or 0?
       if (position == 1) {
           view.getContext().startActivity(new Intent(view.getContext().getApplicationContext(),Route1.class));
       }else{
           Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "Your route is " +
                     parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

       }
   }
   @Override
   public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub

   }
   };
   spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(listener);
   ```